# WSO2 API Manager showing "null" in every text and label of the UI

Tags: wso2

I'm having the same problem presente in this topic.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961129/wso2-api-manager-1-4-publisher-store-ui-not-working

In a browser outside the server, the UI is always showing "null" instead of the right texts of the fields and labels.

The previous link shows an answer, setting the browser language to english, is this the only way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround fix for this. As stated in **Browser Language** section in [1], you can rename

APIM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/locales/jaggery/locale_en.json ,

APIM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/locales/jaggery/locale_en.json

two files, replacing 'en' with your language code.
         ex: If the browser is running on Italy language, rename to locale_it.json.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Quick+Start